# Browser DevTools Default Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, microsoft-edge

Sometimes when I am using the console in devtools (chrome/edge/etc), I use common functions that I write.
For example a sort function or something likewise.

How can I add functions (or classes) by default, so that everytime I open the console these functions or classes are automatically available?

Comment: snipplets......

Comment: @epascarello is there automatically "load" (aka execute) snippets functions when devtools opened?

Comment: If you want them to auto run, you want something like TamperMonkey extension.

Comment: I agree with what epascarello mentioned, because browsers don't have such functionality built in, so you need additional extensions to achieve this.

Comment: Assuming browsers don't have such functionality (which is what I was looking for), the autorun of snippet functions is the thing that comes closest to a viable option.